# Splunk Dashboard to run all enabled Correlation Searches at once

Tags: splunk

Can we create a dashboard in Splunk to run all enabled correlation searches in a specified timeframe at once?

Due to a license issue no alerts were generated for the enabled correlation searches for a certain timeframe.

We want to avoid running manual searches for each rule and create a dashboard which will keep us covered in case of any future outages as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dashboard that uses the `savedsearch` command to invoke correlation searches on your behalf.  You could even use `| rest /servicesNS/-/-/saved/searches` to find the CSs automatically.  It's my understanding, however, that searches invoked via `savedsearch` do not perform any actions so your notables would not get created.